# No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of ‘+’ Haskell

Tags: haskell

I can't figure out why this won't work:

```
final' :: [a] -> a
final' lst = foldl(\accum x -> accum - accum + x) 0 lst
```

I always get the error No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of ‘+’

Comment: `accum - accum + ...`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, I don't quite get your comment (or question) I should be more clear, I am trying to get the last element of the list by using foldl

Comment: @hdizzle `accum - accum` seems like a very awkward way of writing `0`.

Comment: @hdizzle: why do you subtract a number from itself, and not just drop the `accum`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the function itself, but with the *signature* you attach to it yourself:

```
final' :: [a] -> a
```

Here you basically say that your `final'` function will work for *any* `a`. So I could - if I wanted - add `String`s together, as well as `IO ()` instances, or anything else. But now Haskell inspects your function, and notices that you perform an addition `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, with as right operand `x`, which has type `a`. Like the signature for `(+)` already says, both operands should have the *same* type, and that type should be an instance of `Num`.

You can solve the problem by making the signature more restrictive:

```
final' :: Num a => [a] -> a
final' lst = foldl(\accum x -> accum - accum + x) 0 lst
```

In fact we can also generalize a part of the signature, and let it work for any `Foldable`:

```
final' :: (Num a, Foldable f) => f a -> a
final' lst = foldl(\accum x -> accum - accum + x) 0 lst
```

We can however get rid of the `accum`, since subtracting a number from itself, will usually result in zero (except for rounding issues, etc.):

```
final' :: (Num a, Foldable f) => f a -> a
final' = foldl (const id) 0
```

Now we got rid of `(+)` (and `(-)`), but still need to use `Num`. The reason is that you use `0` as initial accumulator, and in case of an empty list, we thus will return `0`, and `0 :: Num n => n`.

Comment: Thanks! but then shouldn't final' :: [a] -> a work without the restriction if I take out the "accum - accum"? so basically --- foldl(\accum x -> x)?

Comment: @hdizzle: no, since - as is written at the end of the answer - you still have `0` as initial accumulator. If the list turns out to be empty, then it will return the initial accumulator, so `0`, and `0` has a type that is an instance of `Num`.